# How to test that async controller is really running async

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have created simple async controllers that call into async methods that then call PostAsync on the HttpClient to retrieve various REST service endpoints.  All works well, but how can I test to insure that the controller is really calling a background thread and releasing the primary thread back to the pool?  I want to insure that I do have all the async sweetness working correctly and that I am not inadvertently running synchronous methods despite all my work to make everything async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread` will provide whether the current thread is still a threadpool thread or not.